# which js event is used to automatically remove focus from the input field?

Tags: javascript

As, I have input field in my site, in which I have to scan the `bar-code` and taking that array to process further, how do I process that after scanning by scanner automatically(not by scrolling mouse or click outside the text box, similarly, as done in any departmental or value store)?basically I am looking for the **JavaScript event** which automatically loses focus or help me to do the same like in departmental store after scanning?

I have used the event `onblur()` but after scanning I have to shift the focus by clicking outside the input field . I want it to be done automatically

Comment: An event is something that happens to you, not something that you do. To remove focus, you can set the focus to something else like the document, with `document.focus()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('link').blur();
},2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** library, **[blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** and **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** functions in it

See this

```js
$('#but').on('click', function(){
  $('input').trigger('blur');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" autofocus>
<button id="but">Lose Focus</button>
```

Or in pure Javascript you can do

```js
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('link').focus();
})

document.getElementById('lose').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('link').blur();
})
```

```html
<a id='link' href="www.google.com">Simple Link<a/>
  <button id="get">Get Focus</button>
<button id="lose">Lose Focus</button>
```

Comment: But I don't want to use jQuery, and the question is not tagged jQuery.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan in your code i have to click a button to remove focus, i just not want to do any activity(clicking or scrolling). As far as the bar-code input, i want it to be processed

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use the blur event to remove focus from the text box or an element

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  
  var textbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
  
  var btn = document.getElementById('loseFocusBtn');
  
  textbox.focus();
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
  
  function btnClick() {
    textbox.blur();
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello, World!" id="myTextBox"/>
<input type="button" value="Lose Focus" id="loseFocusBtn"/>
```